# SubmileText 3 and ScriptCS Intellisense

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, scriptcs, omnisharp

Is there a way to have a C# Intellisense for ScriptCS files in a Submile Text .

I tried to combine OmniSharpSublime plugin with ScriptCS but that doesn't work.

[image: OmniSharpSublime]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OmniSharp doesn't work with ScriptCS files yet, but hopefully soon!

Comment: I guess we need to wait and see.

Answer (score 2):

There's a branch here which should work - https://t.co/N4q8D17oiX

Comment: I approve this message